# How can I automate creating links with spaces in a word / outlook document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook

I'm lazy and I'd like to simplify pasting links with spaces into a word document. I know it can be done by [enclosing a link in chevrons](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook-help/add-links-containing-spaces-to-an-e-mail-message-HA001127242.aspx):

```
<D:\my document.docx>
```

Is there a way to automate that process so you select the bit you want to link, press some keyboard shortcut and voila, it makes it a link with the chevrons to make sure any spaces are handled correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

You will press a key combination, it will copy and edit the value for you. When you paste, your desired string will exist.

EG, instead of pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> , you would press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to trigger this behaviour.

This is about the clipboard in AutoHotKey and should give you more than enough to get going http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Clipboard.htm

Comment: +1 / accepted. I can see a load of other uses for AutoHotKey - thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this useful, the following script will paste these links when you hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>:

```
!v::
SendInput <%clipboard%>{SPACE}
return
```